# Media Element not Play .wmv url link in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my application I have used MediaElement for play .wmv video link.
When play .wmv video link in windows phone 7 it worked perfect and also worked perfect in widnows phone 8 emulator but in
windows phone 8 video not play. Please suggest me.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <MediaElement x:Name="Player" Height="400" Width="400"/>
 </Grid>
```

> MainPage.xaml.cs

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
 Player.Source = new Uri(@"http://domainname/demo.mp42g.wmv", UriKind.Absolute);
       Player.Play();
}

this code worked perfect in windows phone 7 and also worked perfect in widnows phone 8 emulator but windows phone 8 .wmv link not play.
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work, the media is not loaded by the time you say it to play.
Bind an event with your `MediaElement` for `MediaOpened` then in it use `Player.Play();`

This lets the media to load and then if its loaded you can play it.

Also, bind `MediaFailed` to check for exceptions.